# ClosedXML - Sort/Filter of Date Format is wrong

Tags: excel, vb.net, closedxml

I use ClosedXML to create Excel files.
But the Sort of the Date Column doesn't worked correct.
It shows me "Sort A to Z" instead of "Sort Oldest to Newest".

[Sort Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/669BH.png)

But when I enter the same Date manualy, it shows me the correct Sort after I set the Filter.
[Sort Date Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ckaX.png)

Any Ideas how to do this?

A part of My Code

```
Dim wb As New XLWorkbook
Dim ws As IXLWorksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, sdgList.PrimaryGrid.DataMember)
wb.SaveAs(svdg.FileName)
```

I develope in VB.Net but I also Tips for C# are helpful.
I used the ClosedXML Version 0.101.0-rc

I tried to generate the Column of the Datatable als Date or String Format.
And I also try to Format the columns separatly like this

```
ws.Column("J").Style.DateFormat.Format = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```